# "DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework, python-datetime

'2022-11-11'
this is the input value getting from the front end,

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField PaymentChart.date received a naive datetime (2022-11-18 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

this is the error that coming

```
paydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
```

this is how i tried to convert the date, and not working,

i got this error  before, and i added 'tz=datetime.timezone.utc' , it was workin fine then

```
offer.expiry=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)+datetime.timedelta(days=28)
```

but how can i add tz in strptime ??

Comment: use `datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d').replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Django's datetime, and not "datetime" library's datetime:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

offer.expiry=timezone.now()(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)+datetime.timedelta(days=28, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```